# Не отправляются сообщения vk api python

Tags: python, вконтакте

Написал вк бота на python, но почему-то он отвечает только на сообщение "Начать". В чём ошибка?

```
import vk_api
import sqlite3 as sql
import time
import random
connection = sql.connect("user.sqlite", check_same_thread=False)

token = ""

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk._auth_token()

connection.commit()
connection.close()

while True:
    try:
        messages = vk.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 200, "filter": "unanswered"})
        if messages["count"] >= 1:
            id = messages['items'][0]['last_message']['peer_id']
            body = messages['items'][0]['last_message']['text']
            if body.lower() == "начать":
                connection = sql.connect("user.sqlite", check_same_thread=False)
                q = connection.cursor()
                q.execute("SELECT * FROM database WHERE User_ID = '%s'" % (id))
                result = q.fetchall()
                if len(result) == 0:
                    user_info = vk.method("users.get", {"user_ids": id, "fields": "first_name"})
                    user_name = user_info[0]["first_name"]
                    print(str(user_name) + " зарегестрировался")
                    q.execute(
                        "INSERT INTO database (Name, User_ID, Balance, Profit) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (
                        user_name,
                        id, 0, 0))
                    connection.commit()
                    connection.close()
                else:
                    q.execute("SELECT * FROM database WHERE User_ID = %s" % (id))
                    result = q.fetchall()
                    print(result)
                    user_name = result[0][1]
                vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": user_name + """, мои команды:
                Инвестировать [сумма]
                Баланс
                Вывести [сумма]""", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif "Инвестировать" in body.lower():
                connection = sql.connect("user.sqlite", check_same_thread=False)
                q = connection.cursor()
                q.execute("SELECT * FROM database WHERE User_ID = %s" % (id))
                result = q.fetchall()
                if len(result) == 0:
                    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Сначала напишите 'Начать'!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                else:
                    q.execute("SELECT * FROM database WHERE User_ID = %s" % (id))
                    result = q.fetchall()
                    money = result[0][3]
                    plus = int(body.lower().split("Инвестировать ")[-1])
                    if plus < 50000:
                        vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Минимальное пополнение от 50000 монеток!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                        connection.commit()
                        connection.close()
                    else:
                        q.execute("UPDATE database SET Balance = '%s' WHERE User_ID = '%s'" % (int(money) + plus, id))
                        connection.commit()
                        connection.close()
                        vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Баланс пополнен на " + str(plus) + " монеток"})
            elif "Баланс" in body.lower():
                    connection = sql.connect('user.sqlite', check_same_thread=False)
                    q.execute("UPDATE database GET Balance = '%s' WHERE User_ID = '%s'" % (int(money) + plus, id))
                    connection.commit()
                    connection.close()
                    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Ваш баланс: " + str(money) + " монеток", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
            elif "Вывести" in body.lower():
                connection = sql.connect("user.sqlite", check_same_thread=False)
                q = connection.cursor()
                q.execute("SELECT * FROM database WHERE User_ID = %s" % (id))
                result = q.fetchall()
                money = result[0][3]
                minus = int(body.lower().split("Вывести ")[-1])
                if minus > money:
                    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Недостаточно средств для вывода!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
                    connection.commit()
                    connection.close()
                else:
                    q.execute("UPDATE database SET Balance = '%s' WHERE User_ID = '%s'" % (int(money) - minus, id))
                    connection.commit()
                    connection.close()
                    vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Выведено " + str(money) + " монеток", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: а какую ошибку выдает при отправке?

Comment: @teamspam в том то и дело, что никакой ошибки не выдаёт. Просто не отсылает.

Comment: @teamspam скорее всего ответы на остальные команды написаны с ошибкой, так как "Начать" работает нормально, но я не вижу, с какой именно

Comment: офигеть, ну и метод вы выбрали. погуглите longpoll vk api

Comment: `"Инвестировать" in body.lower()` - Вы сообщение приводите к нижнему регистру и сравниваете со словом, содержащим букву верхнего регистра. И да, перейдите на **LongPoll**.